converting hexadecimal string to decimal integer and vice-versa
Here the hexadecimal system is a bit different where A, B .... F are replaced by U-Z.
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    // Write your program logic here. This line is a comment, you can leave it in code if you wish.
    // conversion of hexadecimal to decimal.
    
    //1.taking user input of string
    char hexaDec[10];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        scanf("%c", &hexaDec[i]);
        if(i<=8){
            if(hexaDec[i] == '\n'){
                hexaDec[i+1] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
    // hexaDec[10] = '\0'; wasn't sure if this was required
    
    int dnum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &dnum);
    
    int decimalC = 0;
    int product = 1;
    while(counter>0){
        char cnum = hexaDec[counter-1];
        
        int check = cnum - 'U';
        if(cnum - '0' >= 0 && cnum - '0' <= 9){
            decimalC = decimalC + (cnum - '0') * product;
        }
        else if(check >=0 && check <= 5) {
            decimalC = decimalC + (check + 10)*product;
        }
        
        product = product*16;
        counter--;
    
    }
    printf("%d\n", decimalC);
    
    // //decimal to hexadecimal
    
    char decimalH[10];
    int count = 0;
    if(dnum>0){
        for(count =0; dnum>0  && count<=10; count++){
            int rem = dnum%16;
            dnum = dnum/16;
            if(rem>=0 && rem<=9){
                decimalH[count] = rem +'0';
            }
            else if(rem>=10 && rem<=15){
                decimalH[count] = rem -10 + 'U';
            }
        }        
    }
    
    else if(dnum == 0){
        printf("%c", '0');
    }
    
    while(count>0){
        printf("%c", decimalH[count-1]);
        count--;
    }
    printf("%c", '\0');
    return 0;
}

I know the code is really long and can be simplified using functions but still I wanted to try it with primitive methods. It seems ok for all the problems still the college webpage is telling that I have failed a few cases. I have tried everything I could . Would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

You forgot to ask a question.

Start by reading and converting input in decimal only. And there's no need to store the characters themselves, you can convert any digit (for which isdigit returns a non-zero value) to its integer representation directly and add it to the resulting variable. Once you get that working, adding support for the hex-specific digits is rather easy.

By the way, if the input is too long your current code will not null-terminate the string. Neither does it check for the input to be valid. And int check = cnum - 'U'; is not portable, or working if the user inputs lover-case hex-digits (which are still valid hex-digits), and doesn't really make any sense.

@Some programmer dude could you please tell me how to convert any digit to its integer representation directly ad add it to the resulting variable, a bit more in detail

Does it tell you what the failed test cases are?

@Gerhardh The question had asked to replace the  regular convention A, B, C, ..., F with U-Z alphabets in the hexadecimal system

@Shawn No that's why it was actually getting hard for me to understand my mistakes

int value = 0; char input_char = getchar(); if (isdigit(input_char)) { value = input_char - '0'; } Begin with something like that, and build out from it. And just as there's a isdigit function to check for decimal digits, there's also an isxdigit function. Also remember the basics of the decimal system, that it's based on the value 10.

Also here I had limited the sizes of the character arrays to 10 as that was also requested in the question

@Some programmer dude I will try in this approach and see. Thank you

"taking user input of string" code is convoluted
The need for if(i<=8) is a bit of of a mystery.
decimalC is an odd name for a hexadecimal task.
Decimal to hexadecimal deserves simplification
Might as well use unsigned since sign characters are not processed.
Add error checking

Sample code that is something like OP's:
    // 1. Taking user input of string alternative
    #define INPUT_SIZE 10
    char hexaDec[INPUT_SIZE];
    int counter = 0;
    char ch;

    // Read the _entire_ line, regardless of its length.
    while (scanf("%c", &ch) == 1 && ch != '\n') {
      if (counter < INPUT_SIZE - 1) {
        hexaDec[counter++] = ch;
      } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too long\n");
      }
    }
    // Since the goal is "converting hexadecimal string",
    // append a null character to form a _string_.
    hexaDec[counter] = '\0';


    // Simplify the conversion by walking the string. 
    unsigned value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; hexaDec[i]; i++) {
      int digit;
      if (hexaDec[i] >= '0' && hexaDec[i] <= '9') {
        digit = hexaDec[i] - '0';
      } else if (hexaDec[i] >= 'U' && hexaDec[i] <= 'Z') {
        digit = hexaDec[i] - 'U' + 10;
      } else if (hexaDec[i] >= 'u' && hexaDec[i] <= 'z') {
        digit = hexaDec[i] - 'u' + 10;
      } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not hex\n");
        break;
      }
      value = (value * 16) + digit;
    }

    ...


There is nothing like decimal or hexadecimal integers. There are only integers which can be printed using base 10 or 16 (or any other)
You can convert to any chars representing digits by storing them in the string.
char *mystrchr(const char *str, int ch)
{
    char *result = NULL;

    while(*str && *str != ch) str++;
    return *str ? (char *)str : NULL;
}

const char digits[]="0123456789UWVXYZ";

char *tostrrecursive(char *buff, unsigned long long int val)
{
    if(val) buff = tostrrecursive(buff, val / 16);
    else 
    {
        *buff = 0;
        return buff;
    }
    *buff = digits[val % 16];
    return buff+1;
}

char *tostr(char *buff, unsigned long long int val)
{
    if(val) return tostrrecursive(buff, val);
    else
    {
        buff[0] = digits[0];
        buff[1] = 0;
    }
    return buff;
}

unsigned long long toint(const char *hexstr)
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    while(*hexstr)
    {
        char *found = mystrchr(digits, toupper(*hexstr++));
        result *= 16;
        result += found ? found - digits : 0;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char x[100];
    unsigned long long val;

    tostr(x, 0x1a2b3c4d5e6f);
    //or
    //tostr(x, 28772997619311);
    printf("%s\n", x);
    val = toint(x);
    printf("Printed as hex: %llx\n", val);
    printf("Printed as dec: %llu\n", val);
}

Then you can use any character as a digit.
https://godbolt.org/z/z6fdehGWM
PS I am using unsigned numbers as you in the original code do not care about the sign.

Maybe the college webpage's test was failing when testing negative numbers...

Recursion look fun - for your consideration.

Simplification to @0___________'s fun recursive idea.
static const char digits[] = "0123456789UWVXYZ";

// Return pointer one past last digit.
static char* tostr16recursive(char *buff, unsigned long long int val) {
  #define BASE 16
  if (val >= BASE) {
    buff = tostr16recursive(buff, val / BASE);
  }
  *buff = digits[val % BASE];
  return buff + 1;
}

char* tostr16(char *buff, unsigned long long val) {
  tostr16recursive(buff, val)[0] = '\0';
  return buff;
}

